# output image (mysql, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I a, trying output photo, but can't.

when i write this

```
echo "<p>Name: <b>".$rows['photo']."</b></p>";
```

it say:

> img/car.jpg

but i need a image, so I write

```
echo '<p><img src=img/$rows['photo']/></b></p>';
```

it say

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<p><img src=img/$rows['photo']/></b></p>";
```

or

```
echo '<p><img src=img/'.$rows['photo'].'/></b></p>';
```

Comment: Don't forget braces when referencing an array value in double quotes! `src="img/{$rows['photo']}"`

Comment: when i write second echo '<p><img src=img/'.$rows['photo'].'/></b></p>'; it show icon without photo                                                                and when first it show   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Answer (score 0):

This is correct string manipulation to get what you want:

```
echo "<p><img src=\"{$rows['photo']}\" /></p>";
```

Use `""` as string wrapper to inject variables using curly braces notation.

Also if you have `$rows['photo']` = `img/car.jpg` you will not need extra `img/` in `src` attribute.

And i removed `</b>` tag, since there was no opening tag for it.

Comment: @Jasonartok what do you mean icon? Is there still error?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display the image fetch the image in the separate file and use that file path in the img tag

```
<img  src="fetch_image.php?id='.$id.'"/>
```

$id is a primary key value

Answer (score 0):

The fail is caused by the bad syntax. If we can assume that `$rows['photo']` holds a filename within  `/img` directory then you should use it like this:

```
double quotes here and at the end
     ↓
echo "<p><img src='img/{$rows['photo']}'/></b></p>";
                      ↑              ↑
curly braces to distinguish variables in a string
```

Here's a manual that you need to read in order to understand how it works http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

And last but not least - you have a possible [XSS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vector here because you don't escape value of `$rows['photo']`. That means that if a value of `photo` can be changed by user then user could put, for example this string: `image.jpg' onclick='window.location="my.fishing.website.com";` - that is being the most simple form of this kind of attack (he could also steal cookie values or any other sensitive data).

To mitigate this kind of security hole you need to escape values, which can be influenced by user in any way, with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function. Or even better use templating engine that would it for you: http://www.phptherightway.com/#templating